# Is there a way to asynchronously modify state in Flink KeyedProcessFunction?

Tags: apache-flink

I have two sources, kafka and hbase. In Kafka, there is a data stream in only 24 hours. In Hbase, there is an aggregated data from the beginning. My purpose is that the two data merge on stream processing, when stream input(Kafka) of some session is occurred. I tried a couple of methods but it is not satisfied because of performance.

After some searching, I have an idea with state in keyed process function. The idea is down below. (caching using state of keyed process function)

1. make input to keyed process function using session information
2. check keyed process's state
3. if state is not initialized -> then query from hbase and initialize into state -> go to 5
4. else (state is initialized) -> go to 5
5. do business logic using state

During coding the idea, I have faced performance issue that querying to hbase is slow with sync way. So, I tried async version but it's complicated.

I have faced two issues. One of them is thread-safe issue between processElement and hbase Async worker thread, the other is Context of the process function is expired after end of processElement function (not end of hbase Async worker).

```scala
val sourceStream = env.addsource(kafkaConsumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets())

sourceStream.keyBy(new KeySelector[InputMessage, KeyInfo]() { 
  override def getKey(v: InputMessage): KeyInfo = v.toKeyInfo()
})
  .process(new KeyedProcessFunction[KeyInfo, InputMessage, OUTPUTTYPE]() {

    var state: MapState[String, (String, Long)] = _

    override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
      val conn = ConnectionFactory.createAsyncConnection(hbaseConfInstance).join
      table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("tablename"))

      state = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(stateDescripter)
    }


    def request(action: Consumer[CacheResult] ): Unit = {
      if ( !state.isEmpty ) {
        action.accept(new CacheResult(state))
      }
      else {  // state is empty, so load from hbase
        table.get(new Get(key)).thenAccept((hbaseResult: Result) => {
          // this is called by worker thread
          hbaseResult.toState(state)  // convert from hbase result into state
          action.accept(new CacheResult(state))
        }
      }
    }

    override def processElement(value: InputMessage
                           , ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[KeyInfo, InputMessage, OUTPUTTYPE]#Context
                           , out: Collector[OUTPUTTYPE]): Unit = {
      val businessAction = new Consumer[CacheResult]() {
        override def accept(t: CacheResult): Unit = {
          // .. do business logic here.
          out.collect( /* final result */ )
        }
      }

      request(businessAction)

    }
}).addSink()
```

Is there any suggestion to make KeyedProcessFunction available with async call in third party?

Or any other idea to approach using mixed-up Kafka and Hbase in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

I think your general assumptions are wrong. I faced similar issue but regarding quite different problem and didn't resolve it yet. Keeping state in the program is contradictory with async function and Flink prevents using state in async code by its design (which is a good thing). If you want to make your function async, then you must get rid of the state. To achieve your goal, you probably need to redesign your solution. I don't know all details regarding your problem, but you can think of splitting your process into more pipelines. E.g. you can create pipeline consuming data from hbase and passing it into kafka topic. Then another pipeline can consume data sent by pipeline gathering data from hbase. In such approach you don't have to care about the state becasue each pipeline is doing its own thing, just consuming data and passing it further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :). I understand between state's life cycle and async code in current version. However, I think that keeping state with async function is not impossible to implement, I will try to redesign this issue though.  @Piotr Wittchen

Comment: Also, I tried with AsyncIo function, but same session hits so many times so the performance was much poorer. I might continuously consider this issue and will update when final answer would be popped up.